# how to download a pdf with wget or BS4 from a dynamic javascript page

Tags: javascript, python, wget, python-3.5

On my mobile when I visit the url the browser automatically download the pdf. I'm trying to retrieve or download the pdf using Python

```
import wget
url = 

['https://careers.ottawa.ca/sap/bc/webdynpro/sap/hrrcf_a_posting_apply?PARAM=cG9zdF9pbnN0X2d1aWQ9NTc3QkFCNjBFQ0REMURGQ0UxMDAwMDAwQzBBODI0MTAmY2FuZF90eX
    BlPUVYVA%3d%3d&sap-client=210&sap-language=EN&sap-accessibility=X#',
 'https://careers.ottawa.ca/sap/bc/webdynpro/sap/hrrcf_a_posting_apply?PARAM=cG9zdF9pbnN0X2d1aWQ9NThDQTM2RTg4QzBDMjcxQUUxMDAwMDAwQzBBODI0MTAmY2FuZF90eXBlPUVYVA%3d%3d&sap-client=210&sap-language=EN&sap-accessibility=X#'
        ]
filename = wget.download(url[0])
```

On the page source (Inspect element) I noticed this tag

```
<embed id="plugin" type="application/x-google-chrome-pdf" src="https://careers.ottawa.ca/sap(bD1lbiZjPTIxMA==)/bc/bsp/sap/hrrcf_wd_dovru/application.do?PARAM=cmNmdHlwZT1waW5zdCZwaW5zdD01NzdCQUI2MEVDREQxREZDRTEwMDAwMDBDMEE4MjQxMA%3d%3d" stream-url="blob:chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/906CF02E-9437-45E3-8B77-BEB7950B4BE1" headers="cache-control: no-cache
content-disposition: inline; filename=City_of_Ottawa_JobPoster.pdf
content-length: 30721
content-type: application/pdf
pragma: no-cache
server: SAP NetWeaver Application Server / ABAP 701
">
```

and in the browser when I visit the url contains in the src attribute I can view the pdf but I cannot download it using wget

```
url3= 'https://careers.ottawa.ca/sap(bD1lbiZjPTIxMA==)/bc/bsp/sap/hrrcf_wd_dovru/application.do?PARAM=cmNmdHlwZT1waW5zdCZwaW5zdD01NzdCQUI2MEVDREQxREZDRTEwMDAwMDBDMEE4MjQxMA%3d%3d'
filename = wget.download(url3)
```

I'm getting an error

```
c:\users\gmondesi\appdata\local\continuum\miniconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs)
    587 class HTTPDefaultErrorHandler(BaseHandler):
    588     def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
--> 589         raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    590
    591 class HTTPRedirectHandler(BaseHandler):

HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error
```

Is there a way to download the pdf using `BeautifulSoup`. I couldn't find a static element in the page source that I can rely to download the pdf. The `embed` tag was only found in the `Inspect page source` option in my Browser.

Comment: My tip is to use the html5lib parser with Beautiful Soup. It's way slower than the regular parser,but it sees the page the way a browser does,and maybe that can help you.

Comment: Well, have you actually tried to download the PDF file yourself? Does the webserver work?